# Formula for partial expectation in scipy lognorm

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy.stats

I have just been trying to match the scipy outputs of the lognormal distribution to the formulas on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Partial_expectation).

And I am stuck on the partial expectation with a lower bound.

If I use this simple lognormal distribution:

```
k = .25
sigma = .5
mu = .1 # from the logged variable
lnorm = scist.lognorm(s=sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))
```

where k is the lower bound,

the partial expectation, as I understand it, is given by:

[image]

Fine. So we are simply talking about the mean of the lognormal distribution and a CDF with a z-score. scipy provides the partial

```
lnorm.expect(lambda x:x, lb=k)
>>> 1.25199...
```

Indeed, we can confirm this is the partial by checking it against the conditional expectation. Computing it directly or using the partial above yield the same result:

```
 lnorm.expect(lambda x:x, lb=k) / (1 - lnorm.cdf(k))
 >>> 1.25385... 
 lnorm.expect(lambda x:x, lb=k, conditional=True)
 >>> 1.25385...
```

However, scipy's `cdf` function takes the `x` variable, not the z-score and I am uncertain how to transform this:

[image]

Into an `x` value. I have tried many different flavors.

I would have thought:

[image]

would do the trick to account for the subtraction of mu that must occur when scipy's `cdf` (presumably) computes the z-score internally.

Any formulation I use ends up with a very small or 0 value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me what your question actually is. You want to compute the partial expectation with a `def` using the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply compute the CDF of a Normal distribution N(0,1) in (mu+sigma^2-ln(k))/2, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps

def partial_expectation(mu, sigma, k):
    """
    Returns partial expectation given
    mean, standard deviation and k.
    
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution
    """
    # compute cumulative density function
    # of Normal distribution N(0,1) in x=x_phi
    x_phi = (mu + sigma**2 - np.log(k))/sigma
    phi = sps.norm.cdf(x_phi, loc=0, scale=1)
    # mean of lognormal
    lognorm_mu = np.exp(mu + .5*(sigma**2))
    # result
    return lognorm_mu * phi

k = .25
sigma = .5
mu = .1 # from the logged variable
lnorm = sps.lognorm(s=sigma, scale=np.exp(mu))

print('from def:', partial_expectation(mu, sigma, k))
print('from sps:', lnorm.expect(lb=k))

from def: 1.251999952174895
from sps: 1.2519999521748952
```